# Data not displayed through switch case Angular

Tags: angular

I am just getting started with angular and I was exploring conditionals in Angular with switch case.

So I have a service that provides a list of objects.
Each object has a name and a type
The three possible types are char, book and house.

I have verified that the data is valid through a console.log

Now in my main template, I'm using switch case like this

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let item of dataSet" [ngSwitch]="item.type">
    <app-char-item *ngSwitchCase="char" [charItem]="item"></app-char-item>
    <app-house-item *ngSwitchCase="house" [houseItem]="item"></app-house-item>
    <app-book-item *ngSwitchCase="book" [bookItem]="item"></app-book-item>
    <div *ngSwitchDefault>{{item.type}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`dataSet` is an array that contains all the objects.

For now, each component just shows the name property of the object passed in.

I am using `@Input()` to receive data in the individual components.

But for some reason, no data is displayed on the page. The console is 
clean and shows no errors.

I tried using a default case and printed out the type property. The default case is executed but the type properties have the same spelling as the switch case, so there should be no reason to execute the default block.

NOTE: `dataSet` has a type of `Any[]`. So it basically accommodates different types of objects in it.

Comment: Please create a StackBlitz if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Angular switch is by default, asking for expressions to evaluate.

This means the correct syntax is an expression. For instance :

```
*ngSwitchCase="1 === 1"
```

You can use an implicit expression, but if you do, consider that you are in a "expression-required" syntax. So try this instead (you can remove spaces, I used it to show you the quotes) :

```
*ngSwitchCase=" 'char' "
```

This is explained by its "sugarized" syntax : `*ngSwitchCase`.

When you write this, Angular transforms it to this :

```
<ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="'char'">
  <app-char-item [charItem]="item"></app-char-item>
</ng-template>
```

Because it uses the input syntax `[ngSwitchCase]`, you have to provide JS code, not strings, like you would do with an `@Input`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control if the value of the variable `item.type` equals to `'char'` as a string or so on, what you should do is the following:

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let item of dataSet" [ngSwitch]="item.type">
    <app-char-item *ngSwitchCase="'char'" [charItem]="item"></app-char-item>
    <app-house-item *ngSwitchCase="'house'" [houseItem]="item"></app-house-item>
    <app-book-item *ngSwitchCase="'book'" [bookItem]="item"></app-book-item>
    <div *ngSwitchDefault>{{item.type}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, you try to match the value of `item.type` with the value of a varible called `char` (I guess it is undefined for your case, since it is probably not defined anywhere in your code).